# Formula to Retrieve Multiple Column Numbers in Which a Value Appears

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to use an on sheet formula that will provide me with all the column numbers in which a value exists.  For the sake of example:  I want to find all the columns on `Sheet1` that have a value of `ThisHeader` in `Row1`.

I have been able to use the below formula to retrieve the result I want if the value I'm searching for only appears one time:

`=MATCH("ThisHeader",1:1,0)`

I'm unsure how to implement this same logic, but give me multiple column numbers if `ThisHeader` exists in multiple columns.

I'm not particular about how the result is displayed, although ideally I'd use something like: `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,col_number,4),"1","")` after the column numbers are retrieved in order to translate to a letter format. perhaps with a comma or dash separating each number/column letter.  I could add or use multiple formulas and columns rather than a nested formula as well if that is the best or only route.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Match and other lookup functions only ever return one result. Please mock up a data sample and also mock up what the expected result should look like. All results in one cell? Separated by what? Or results in different cells? Be precise, no "perhaps this or that". In any case, this will require some kind of recursion that is not easily done with worksheet functions, but very doable with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have O365, you can use:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($1:$1="ThisHeader")*COLUMN($1:$1),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF($1:$1,"ThisHeader")))
```

If you do not have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can replace it and use:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($1:$1="ThisHeader")*COLUMN($1:$1),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF($1:$1,"ThisHeader"))))
```

[image]

**Results**

[image]

The formula returns an array of the column numbers. So, to visualize them if you don't have the dynamic array feature of recent Excel versions, you may have to enter this as an array formula (with `ctrl+shift+enter` over multiple cells. Or by using an `INDEX` function to return each element.